# How to get information for an own xml-editor from corresponding xsd'S?

Tags: java, xml, autocomplete, xsd, editor

I would like to writen an xml-editor in java and would like to get informations for a xml element like possible child-elements, documentation using the corresponding xsd.
For validation i can use this simple code fragment but i dont think it helps me to get informations for one specific element in the xml:

```
 StreamSource[] schemaDocuments = { new StreamSource("layout.xsd") };
        /* created by your application */;
        Source instanceDocument = new StreamSource("BEW.xml");
        /* created by your application */;

        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(
                "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        Schema s = sf.newSchema(schemaDocuments);

        Validator v = s.newValidator();

        v.validate(instanceDocument);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EMF project is a modeling framework and code generation facility for building tools and other applications based on a structured data model.

https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/

See http://blog.xequtor.com/post/2017/06/12/emf-create-ecore-model-from-xsd-file for an example project.

I have seen it used very successfully to generate editors for various complex data models, and I have written code to load XSDs and iterate over their content using EMF. Its implementation of the XSD standard is very thorough - it will load xs:includes and xs:imports and will validate the XSDs against the rules in the W3C specification.